# Output pre-json encoded string to spring framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a json:object I'm serving.  As part of that json document, I want to serve some pre-encoded json.  unfortunately, once served, the pre-encoded json is re-encoded.  Is there a way to escape that property so it's simply served?

```
<json:property name="data"><c:out value="${overlay.boundry}"/></json:property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that `overlay.boundry` been HTML encoded. If so, then you just need to remove the `c:out` tag like this:

```
<json:property name="data">${overlay.boundry}</json:property>
```

or, if you really like JSTL tags:

```
<json:property name="data"><c:out value="${overlay.boundry}" escapeXml="false" /></json:property>
```

Comment: It's still encoded: {&#034;x&#034;:&#034;-78.09537&#034;,&#034;y&#034;:&#034;44.371172&#034;}

Comment: Does it have to be escaped before it's sent to the template?

Comment: I escaped the property tag as well: <json:property name="data"  escapeXml="false"><c:out value="${overlay.boundry}" escapeXml="false" /></json:property>  This is result: {\"x\":\"-78.060661\",\"y\":\"44.291723\"}

Comment: Got it.  Did an eval on the json property.  Not ideal, but it works.